# How to Turn Off Shadow Copies for Specific Folders/Files

Tags: windows-home-server, volume-shadow-copy

I currently am using Windows Home Server 2011 and all of my shared folders (well, actually the volume that all of those shares are on) use the shadow copies of files. Is there a way to disable shadow copies for specific folders/files? Ultimately, I have no need for, and would prefer not to, create and keep shadow copies of the contents of the Recorded TV share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how to exclude files: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa819132(v=vs.85).aspx

http://www.mydigitallife.info/exclude-files-from-shadow-copies-previous-versions-and-system-restore/